# Eigenvalues and positivity of Hermitian Toeplitz matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to check the eigenvalues (and also the positivity) of the $n \times n$ complex Toeplitz matrix

\begin{equation}
T = \begin{bmatrix}
r & z_1 & z_2 & z_3 &\cdots & z_{n-1}\\
\bar{z}_1 & r & z_1 & z_2 & \cdots & z_{n-2}\\
\bar{z}_2 & \bar{z}_1 & r & z_1 & \cdots & z_{n-3}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\bar{z}_{n-1} & \bar{z}_{n-2} & \bar{z}_{n-1} & \cdots & \cdots & r
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}.
\end{equation}
$\bar{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$, and $r$ is a real number. Is there a canonical way to calculate the eigenvalues of the above matrix?

I am sure,this question has been answered somewhere in the stackexchange, but I can not determine where. Please help.